# 720kb/angular-socialshare : Is it possible to have an email template when sharing via email

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, socialshare

I tried inserting an html tags for the socialshare-body for email sharing to check if html tags can be used for email sharing. Unfortunately, it is not working. Is there a way that I can share via email using an email template ?

```
<span socialshare socialshare-provider='email'
      socialshare-subject='Please see my review {{reviewLink}}'
      socialshare-body='<strong>TEST</strong>'>
      <i class='fa fa-envelope'></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Modified the post

Comment: What does not working mean? Is your template missing the bindings?

Comment: It is showing as plain text instead  of having a bold text